# IIS Express / Visual Studio Dev Server Crashing on specified machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

we are experiencing a problem with a mvc 4 projects,
the project works perfect on 3 of 4 machines for debuging but the fourth simpy wont get started for debugging. IIS Express starts up but crashes immediately.
However it can compile and deploy perfectly but it wont run the web application.

what we have tried so far:
reinstalling visual studio, .net framework, cleaning solution, changing the libraries/dlls to higher / lower versions, reinstalling iis, resetting iis, using the standrad webdev server from vs2012, cleaning all temp files, copied the whole solution one by one,  reinstalling mvc and any other component, manually adding the assemblies and changing web.config, updating the packages via nuget but it keeps crashing after launching iis with the follow error:

```
Die Datei oder Assembly "Microsoft.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

(Data or Assmebly ... or a Dependency could not be found)

```
=== Zustandsinformationen vor Bindung ===
LOG: Benutzer = SST\windischhofer
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Projekte/ProjekteWeb/WatShop/WatShop/
LOG: Ursprünglicher PrivatePath = C:\Projekte\ProjekteWeb\WatShop\WatShop\bin
Aufruf von Assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: Diese Bindung startet im default-Load-Kontext.
LOG: Die Anwendungskonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: C:\Projekte\ProjekteWeb\WatShop\WatShop\web.config
LOG: Die Hostkonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: C:\Users\Windischhofer\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Die Computerkonfigurationsdatei von C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config wird verwendet.
LOG: Verweis nach der Richtlinie: Microsoft.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/fd001a0f/c504da06/Microsoft.Data.DLL.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/fd001a0f/c504da06/Microsoft.Data/Microsoft.Data.DLL.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Projekte/ProjekteWeb/WatShop/WatShop/bin/Microsoft.Data.DLL.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Projekte/ProjekteWeb/WatShop/WatShop/bin/Microsoft.Data/Microsoft.Data.DLL.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/fd001a0f/c504da06/Microsoft.Data.EXE.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/fd001a0f/c504da06/Microsoft.Data/Microsoft.Data.EXE.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Projekte/ProjekteWeb/WatShop/WatShop/bin/Microsoft.Data.EXE.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Projekte/ProjekteWeb/WatShop/WatShop/bin/Microsoft.Data/Microsoft.Data.EXE.
```

Stack Trace

```
[FileNotFoundException: Die Datei oder Assembly "Microsoft.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +675
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +1231
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +618
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +510
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +352
   Microsoft.WebPages.Configuration.PreApplicationStartCode.LoadAssembly(String name, Version version, String publicKeyToken) +487
   Microsoft.WebPages.Configuration.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +462

[InvalidOperationException: Von der Methode "Start" des Typs "Microsoft.WebPages.Configuration.PreApplicationStartCode" für die Initialisierung vor dem Anwendungsstart wurde eine Ausnahme mit folgender Fehlermeldung ausgelöst: Die Datei oder Assembly "Microsoft.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +1247
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +356
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath) +424
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +431
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1458

[HttpException (0x80004005): Von der Methode "Start" des Typs "Microsoft.WebPages.Configuration.PreApplicationStartCode" für die Initialisierung vor dem Anwendungsstart wurde eine Ausnahme mit folgender Fehlermeldung ausgelöst: Die Datei oder Assembly "Microsoft.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +1037
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +392
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +578
```

any clue would be highly appreciated

regards jan

edit: about the machines used:
the three were its working are using windows 8 / visual studio 2013 the one where it simply wont work runs windows 7 / vs 2013 the project is sourcecontrolled via tfs